# Get List of all PSSessions for all users

Tags: powershell

I am trying to connect with a remote PSSession to a server, but I am receiving the following error:

> The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The maximum
>   number of concurrent shells allowed for this plugin has been exceeded.
>   Retry the request later or raise the Maximum Shells per Plugin quota.
>   For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I understand that I can increase the number of shells per user, but I would like to determine the cause of this error to alleviate it in the future. When I run a Get-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost" on the remote computer, no output is returned (implying my user does not have any sessions open). Is there a way for me to get all sessions for all users on the remote computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Get-WSManInstance cmdlet, such as:

```
Get-WSManInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -ResourceURI Shell -Enumerate
```

Here's a post about how I used the cmdlet, and made it a part of a function to run the same command against multiple computers: http://tommymaynard.com/quick-learn-determine-if-theres-a-current-powershell-remoting-session-2016/.

Comment: The command returned nothing on the server that was throwing the error. I connected via PSSession to a different server from my local computer with two different accounts. I then logged onto the server via RDP as one of those users and ran your command and it output both of the connections from both users exactly as explained in your blog. Is there any other way that this error could be thrown?

Comment: I am upvoting and accepting your answer as it is the correct solution to getting the list of all open remote powershell sessions from all users. However, I am still seeing this error raised when trying to establish a new connection to servers that do not return anything from this command. If you have any input or suggestions as to other methods I could try, I would greatly appreciate it!